# Power shell to output script to logfile

Tags: powershell

i have this script to get all files not not accessed since 12/31/16. it runs fine, but how can i output the results to a log file ?

```
$date = "12/31/2016"
Get-ChildItem T:\ -Recurse | where{$_.LastWriteTime -le [DateTime]$date}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, piping to Out-File cmdlet?

```
$date = "12/31/2016"

Get-ChildItem T:\ -Recurse | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -le [DateTime]$date } | Out-File oldfiles.log
```